# How to update multiple select option in mysql db with php

Tags: php, html, pdo

Im actually saving some data in my db using PDO but i am facing issue with the multiple select dropdown. I dont have any problem with insertion cause my script adds the data perfectly the way i want it, the only issue comes with updating the data cause  only the last selected option updates all the rows. I would like to know what i did wrong and why only the last selected option is updating.

HTML

```
<input type='text' name='customer'>
<select name='engineer_id[]' id='engineer' multiple>
<?php

foreach($engineers as $engineer){
  $engineersList = explode(',', $engineer['engineer_id']);
  if (isset($engineer['user_id'])) {
    $mfi_engineers = in_array($engineer['user_id'], $engineersList);
    //if ($engineer['user_id'] === $engineer['engineer_id']) {
    if ($mfi_engineers) {
      echo "<option value=".$engineer['user_id']." selected>".$engineer['fullname']."</option>";
    } else {
      echo "<option value=".$engineer['user_id'].">".$engineer['fullname']."</option>";
    }
  }
}

?>
</select>
```

SERVER SIDE

```
<?php

$engineersArr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'engineer_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
$customerName = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'customer', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)); 

// Send array data to the model for updating
foreach( $engineersArr as $engineer => $engineersId ) {
  $update_response = updateCustomer($customerName, $engineersId)
}

// UPDATE QUERY FUNCTION

function updateCustomer($customerName, $engineersId): int
{
  try {
    $db = createConnection();
    $sql = 'UPDATE customers SET cus_name = :customerName, engineer_id = :engineer_id, WHERE cus_name = :customerName';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':customerName', $customerName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':engineer_id', $engineersId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rowsChanged = $stmt->rowCount();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    return $rowsChanged;
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    return 0;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the $customerName value? and what exactly do you want to update? here you are updating the $customerName to $engineersId, but the customerName source is not clear.

Comment: `...engineer_id = :engineer_id, WHERE...` oops. A comma after `engineer_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `customerName` that equals "Joe". Joe has 4 engineers, so the 4 `engineersId`'s are: `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. Your UPDATE query [typo fixed]:

```
UPDATE customers SET cus_name = :customerName, engineer_id = :engineer_id WHERE cus_name = :customerName
```

...evaluates to:

```
UPDATE customers SET cus_name = "Joe", engineer_id = 1 WHERE cus_name = "Joe"
UPDATE customers SET cus_name = "Joe", engineer_id = 2 WHERE cus_name = "Joe"
UPDATE customers SET cus_name = "Joe", engineer_id = 3 WHERE cus_name = "Joe"
UPDATE customers SET cus_name = "Joe", engineer_id = 4 WHERE cus_name = "Joe"
```

First ALL Joe's `engineer_id`'s are set to `1`—then ALL to `2`—then ALL to `3`...

If you are updating all of Joe's engineers, and not simply adding more to Joe's list, then first `DELETE` all Joe's records and `INSERT` his updated list.